# Program that replaces multiple blanks and tabs into single blank and tab

Tags: c

I'm reading **The C Programming Language**.

I have used this program to replace multiple blanks to single blanks but I want to replace multiple blanks and tabs into single blank and tab in same time

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            putchar(c);
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
                ;
        }
        if (c != ' ')
            putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"into single blank and tab in same time"* is not completely clear. You should provide some examples of given input and expected output. Use `\t` to describe a tab.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is almost correct: there is a problem if the file ends with a space as the inner loop `while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');` will stop and the end of file leaving `c` with the value `EOF`, which will be output as the byte `0xFF` (if `EOF` is defined as `-1`, the most common value).

You should check for this possibility:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            putchar(c);
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
                continue;
            if (c != EOF)
                break;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is unclear what you mean by *replace multiple blanks and tabs into single blank and tab*.

To replace both spaces and TABs with a single space, you just need to test both byte values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t') {
            putchar(' ');
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
                continue;
            if (c != EOF)
                break;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Conversely, if you mean to replace multiple spaces with a single space and multiple TABs with a single TAB, a different approach can be used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, last = EOF;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t') {
            if (c == last)
                continue;
        }
        putchar(c);
        last = c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This approach can be used for the original problem and produces simpler code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, last = EOF;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ' || c != last) {
            putchar(c);
            last = c;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```